# Prevent chrome cutting off background images on body when using background-position

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-position

I have a background image of a paper airplane on the body tag of this page: http://cogo.goodfolk.co.nz. The very tip of it is being cut off - if you resize the browser window the full image pops back in.

It's only happening in Chrome, and isn't consistent, if you refresh sometimes, or even hover over sometimes it's fine. If I remove all the background styles (background position and no-repeat) then the whole image is there - but of course isn't positioned correctly. It's also happening on other pages of my website (eg http://cogo.goodfolk.co.nz/online-surveying).

After days of debugging/searching I can't find anything that refers to this issue and/or fixes it - is it possibly a Chrome bug with background-position?

Any ideas or workarounds? Thank you!

//EDITED//
The relevant code is pasted below, although obviously this is pretty standard so it must be something else in the site that's causing the problem:

```
.home {
   background: url("../img/airplane.jpg") no-repeat center; 
   background-size: 70%;
   background-position: 10% 98%;
}
```

Comment: I think it's highlight dependent on your screen. I resized my browser and then maximized it, I still see the tip is within the viewport. Am on a 1600x900 monitor. You may need to listen to viewport resizes and hardcode specific background positions for different sizes.

Comment: I am unable to recreate this problem on Chrome, regardless of viewport size...

Comment: Thank you guys for taking a look at this - sorry you weren't able to reproduce, it's a pretty subtle bug. I was able to reproduce on the two macs and one pc that I tested it on. Anyway, I've figured out a work around. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay thanks to everyone who left suggestions, fortunately I've figured out a workaround! I managed to pretty much keep the background styles the same, and just placed everything in a :before pseudo element on the body tag. You can check out the updated code at cogo.goodfolk.co.nz if you're interested, or it's pasted here:

```
.home {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 860px;
}
.home:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url("../img/airplane.jpg") no-repeat center;
   background-size: 70%;
   background-position: 50% 15%;
}
```

Comment: It's often a good idea to include the relevant code within your question and answer for future reference, in case of future revisions to the site's code.

Comment: @RebeccaHill Instead of min-height to some specific value. I suggest to use `min-height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

The background image is set to `center`, so this is expected behaviour, depending on window size.  You could change this CSS declaration from:

```
.home {
    background: url("../img/airplane.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 70%;
}
```

To:

```
.home {
    background: url("../img/airplane.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 70%;
}
```

This would anchor the image to the top of the screen, meaning it would not clip, but this may not be the behaviour you are looking for.

To complicate matters, you also have this, which is probably contributing to the problem.  I would suggest removing it entirely:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.home {
    background-position: 20% -10%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice @graphicdivine. I wasn't quite sure why you suggested that the top of the image cutting off was expected behaviour - to be clear it was cutting off before it reached the edge of the browser, as if there was some kind of margin or encapsulating div (which there wasn't). I did try your suggestions but you were right, they didn't create the kind of behaviour I was looking for. Thank you anyway, fortunately I've figured out a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Set the display to "inline-table".

Comment: Please include a bit more detail - what part of the code needs to be changed?